# Почему в результате выводится 117642?

Tags: c#

```
int a = 153;
Console.Write(Math.Pow(a.ToString()[0], 3));
```

Вроде бы как "1" должно выводиться, так как 1 в кубе будет равно самому себе...

Comment: Очень странно, так как должно выводиться 117 649‬. 1 имеет номер 49 в таблице ascii, 49 в кубе = 117 649‬

Answer (score 2):

потому что приводишь число к string, берешь первый элемент по индексу, а это char, у тебя там цифра 1, у нее аски код 49, а 49^3 = 117649

Answer (score 2):

Потому что вы передаете методу не цифру 1, а код символа 1, чтобы получить желаемый результат вам нужно переписать пример так:

```
int a = 153;
Console.Write(Math.Pow(Char.GetNumericValue(a.ToString()[0]), 3));
```